# preferred free project management + SCM tool combination

Tags: java, open-source, project-management, collaboration, version-control

**What is the preferred free open source project management and SCM tool combination for working on multiple java based projects?**

This must be something that has been answered on here before but i couldnt find a good one.

Im working with a couple people on two different proof-of-concept web app projects and have been doing everything together so far. We are about to the point where we would like to utilize some source control code management software as well as a compatable project management tool. We are considering [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) with [SVN](http://subversion.apache.org/), would like to know what the preferences of some of you guys out there were before we were forced to do a bunch of analytical comparisons.

Anyway, this seems like the type of questions that must have been ask before, so if someone could add their thoughts or point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!!!

PS: these projects will ultimately be ported to first android then iphone, if that carries any weight with your preferences

[similar stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84303/code-document-management-for-a-very-small-company)

Comment: Sometimes I think it'd be a lot simpler for everyone if SO just set up a filter preventing all questions containing the words "the best".

Comment: "best" == subjective and argumentative

Comment: Also... I'll probably mark what we end up using as the answer, or add another comment if we use something different, but that probably wont be decided for another week or so... Thanks again for all your recommendations!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using Atlassian suite (Confluence/JIRA + JIRA Studio) and are quite happy about it. See www.atlassian.com (no affiliation, just like the product).

Comment: Seconded, the entire Atlassian Suite is really well put together.

Comment: I'm a big fan of the confluence/jira combo also

Comment: These tools do look pretty awesome and not THAT expensive, but we are trying to minimize our startup overhead. Because of this we will be looking for free tools. I apologize for not emphasizing this earlier.

However... that first year for $10 deal they're offering is mighty tempting!!

Answer (score 0):

svn is the easyest to use and git is very powerfull

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree with comment about git, but neither of them is a tool for project management.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) + Git back-end for a number of projects.

You definitely want something that handles refactoring better than SVN for Java. In SVN, it is a pain to, say, change the package for a class; Git will auto-detect the change.