# NUnit vs Team System Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

Which do you prefer?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each for Unit Testing?

EDIT: I will admit that Team System offers a lot more than just Unit Testing, such as performance and load testing of applications and databases.  This question was centering around writing unit tests and which do you prefer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554018/unit-test-nunit-or-visual-studio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Nunit:**

Advantages:

- Free
- Very similar to team system in attributs and methods for assertion, some names are even the same

Disadvantages:

- Tests must be run via console or external application ( this can be seen as an advantage, but not from my point of view).

**Team System testing**

Advantages:

- A part of VS, you can run tests in a test window.
- If you run a team system server you can run tests more easily as a part of the automated build

Disadvantages:

- Expensive
- Still isn't as stable as NUnit

[A comparison between team system and Nunit](http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/teamsystem/archive/2006/02/03/Comparing_nUnit_to_Team_System_Unit_Testing.aspx)

*We use team system 2008 as we are gold certified partners to microsoft, but earlier used Nunit due to bug related issues in VS 2005. I prefer the VS soluti*on.

*Both are good solutions for your work, look also out for other free solutions like:*

[Good alternatives to Team System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857/what-do-you-use-as-a-good-alternative-to-team-system)

Comment: Running NUnit tests with Resharper or TestDriven.net is also completely integrated in VS, with tests running in a test window etc etc.

Comment: TestDriven intergration is too weak  though I'd prefer something like testmatrix. Also Resharper is great as well.

Comment: Yeah, I looked into TestDriven.  But, it's $$$.

Comment: In vs2008 its unfair to compare with team system only based on unit testing (as that is a small piece of what you get). Specially considering you do have unit tests in the professional edition in vs 2008.

Answer (score 6):

One very specific reason, is that NUnit won't tie you to the professional edition of the visual studio.

**Update:** Here is a link about unit testing support on **Professional** edition in vs 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385902.aspx

Comment: @Eric no, I meant exactly that, check the link in my update to the answer

Answer (score 4):

One other advantage of NUnit is that it doesn't require that you add anything to your test classes. MSTest requires the presence of a TestContext property. We started out with MSTest but converted to NUnit. I also find NUnit to be significantly faster and I prefer ReSharper's test runner UI.

Comment: @Jamie you can leave the testcontext out if you want i.e. this would run:
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest3
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(2, 2);
        }
    }

Answer (score 4):

Currently NUnit has **test categories** that allow you to run unit tests separately from slower integration tests.

MS Tests has no such built-in mechanism.

Comment: @total you can run all tests in the current context, which means: a single test, a class or a whole namespace. With appropiate namespace you can do it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant from a TFS Build or the MSTest command line. To do something equivalent you would have to specify individual tests or manually create a list of tests in a vsmdi file.

Answer (score 2):

When using MS Tests, you can use [CHESS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/):

> CHESS is a tool for systematically testing multithreaded code. Given a concurrent test, CHESS systematically drives the test along all possible thread interleavings.

Also, I found a nice comparison [here](http://www.artofunittesting.com/Chapters/Tools_and_frameworks) that claims MS Tests are a little slower than NUnit, but I didn't check it myself.

Comment: I'm looking at CHESS now for some sync testing, but all our unit tests here on Stack Overflow are in NUnit; I guess the threading tests must be with MSTest.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't Visual Studio 2008 allow you to use other testing frameworks when you create the test project?  I vaguely remember this from watching the old MVC Framework videos back when Hanselman was doing the preview 2 or 3 videos.

This would allow you to use any testing framework you like and still be able to use it in your VS2008 IDE.

Answer (score 1):

What about testing private methods. 
Team System create automatically shadow accessors using reflections - does NUnit same?

Answer (score 0):

There is always tools like ReSharper and TestDriven.NET. They will let you run tests from Visual Studio