# how to use nunit with visual studio

Tags: nunit, nunit-2.5

Visual studio has a built-in unit test framework. I am wondering if I can use nunit instead?

Comment: Have you use search to try to find the solution within already asked questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [TestDriven.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/), [Nunit](http://nunitit.codeplex.com/) and [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/index.jsp) provide integration with VS. More details in the two posts below (in response to the same question).

[Unit test, NUnit or Visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554018/unit-test-nunit-or-visual-studio/1554058#1554058)

and

[Unit test, NUnit or Visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554018/unit-test-nunit-or-visual-studio/1554038#1554038)

Answer (score 1):

### Using NUnit without extensions

This answer is long overdue, but I'm using NUnit in Visual Studio without any additional extensions (that are mainly also not free).

The whole idea is to configure your test project (a usual Class library project actually) so that when you hit **F5** or **Ctrl-F5** it automatically starts NUnit GUI and starts test execution.

The main benefit of [this project configuration](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/running-or-debugging-nunit-tests-from.html) (all configuration steps are described with images) is that it's easy to also debug your tests if you need to when you have bugs in them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a free Visual Studio addin for NUnit: [NUnitAddin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nunitaddin2/files/NUnitAddin-binaries/1.1.2/)