# Teamcity 2017.2 vs Team Foundation Server 2018

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

Hello we are deciding at our project to move from Teamcity to TFS 2018 but we are not sure if its best idea. I was reading a lot comparison but they are pretty old 2 years is in programming world really lot. We like about tfs 2018 that it support it own nugget server it has own version control technicaly you can have everything at one place. Can you please give some pros and cons of both?

Comment: pros: TeamCity is better.  
cons:  TFS is bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Team Foundation Build or TeamCity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239249/team-foundation-build-or-teamcity)

Comment: But that question is from 2010 and last answer is from 2016. I think in 2 years a lot of stuff can happen and things could change in 2 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this article to [Compare TeamCity Vs. Team Foundation Server](https://www.itqlick.com/Compare/teamcity/team-foundation-server)

> ### About the vendors - JetBrains Vs. Microsoft
>
> **JetBrains:** JetBrains, creator of the best Java IDE - IntelliJ IDEA - is a technology-leading software development firm specializing in the creation of intelligent development.At JetBrains, we have a
>   passion for making people more productive through smart software
>   solutions that help them focus more on what they really want to
>   accomplish, and less on mundane, repetitive "computer busy work".
>
> **Microsoft:** Microsoft Corporation is an American corporation that develops, manufactures, licenses and supports a wide range of products
>   and services related to computing. The company was founded by Bill
>   Gates and Paul Allen on April 4, 1975. Microsoft is the world's
>   largest software maker measured by revenues.
>
> ### Compare Pricing - TeamCity Vs. Team Foundation Server
>
> TeamCity Starting from $299 Per license, Team Foundation Server
>   Starting from $20 Per month/user. .
>
> ### Compare Features and Functionality
>
> As with any business software solutions, it’s important to consider
>   features & functionality. The tool should support the processes,
>   workflows, reports and needs that matter to your team. To help you
>   evaluate this, we've compared TeamCity Vs. Team Foundation Server
>   based on some of the most important and required Enterprise
>   Integration features.
>
> **TeamCity:** Data Import/Export, Basic Reports, Online Customer Support.
>
> **Team Foundation Server** list of features include the following: Data Import/Export, Basic Reports, Online Customer Support,
>
> ### Mobile Friendly / Cloud
>
> **TeamCity:** their software can be used in the following: Standalone, On Premise while Team Foundation Server can be used with: Standalone,
>   Cloud, SaaS
>
> ### Which Software is Better? TeamCity or Team Foundation Server?
>
> Which solution is better? TeamCity or Team Foundation Server? As
>   usual, the question is not “Which software is better?” but “Which
>   software is right for your needs and budget?”. Neither of these two
>   Enterprise Integration software is necessarily “better” than the
>   other. Both offer industry-leading features and a scalable platform,
>   as well as the ability to custom-build a unique solution with optional
>   modules. If you would like to get quotes or having trouble deciding
>   which Enterprise Integration is the right for you, we’d love to help.
>   Fill out the forms in this page to get demos, free quotes and a custom
>   software recommendation.

---

Besides, you can integrate TeamCity with Team Foundation Server as needed to combine their advantages.

> Without installing additional software, TeamCity servers and build
>   agents can interact with Team Foundation Servers (from 2010 to 2017;
>   2018 is supported since TeamCity 2017.2) and Visual Studio Team
>   Services.

Please refer to below articles to know more about that:

- [Cross-Platform TFS Integration](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Team+Foundation+Server)
- [Integrating TeamCity with Team Foundation Server](https://roadtoalm.com/2015/07/16/integrating-teamcity-with-team-foundation-server-part-1/)