# Moving from SVN to TFS

Tags: svn, version-control, tfs

I come from an environment using subversion with TortoiseSVN for source control. Now in a new area, I will be using TFS.

I have a couple of questions, i'm sure more will follow ;-) :

- What things should I keep in mind when moving across
- It obviously (I hope!) has all the same features, where I can commit changes with comment, revert back, compare changes between different dated source files, etc.
- Should I be happy with this change, or try to push a change back to SVN. Or, in your opininon, which is better?

Thanks,

Comment: here is a similar question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219/experience-with-svn-vs-team-foundation-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find very similar features in both Subversion with TortoiseSVN and Team Foundation Server, although TFS is much better integrated into Visual Studio. There is no killer feature or issue that would cause me to recommend switching from TFS to Subversion, if anything the integrated nature of TFS would have me recommending switching TO TFS.

TFS also has the benefit of task / bug tracking all built in, so you have everything in one development tool.

Comment: SVN hardware and software recommendation is very much lower than TFS. Its deployment is very easier than TFS too.

Comment: @afsharm - They are already using TFS, so actually that's a moot point as it is already deployed on the required hardware - so your comment is an argument for staying on TFS.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say as VCSs they're roughly comparable. TFS is probably a bit easier to use, though there are some weird behaviours to get used to. For example, if you delete a local file then "get latest" it won't necessarily pull that file down.

TFS does have some nice integration features for unit testing, bug/task tracking etc.

Answer (score 0):

Branching in TFS is much nicer than SVN.